# How to dynamically populate Jira custom fields?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I'm new to the Jira admin side of things after having used it in a previous company as an end-user for several years.  We are using the standard Jira workflow. The scenario I'm struggling with is the following.  I'm attempting to match some of the functionality of our old-proprietary issue database.  Right now I'm using many of the standard Jira fields, with only two new custom fields (both single Select Lists populated manually by me):

1) Customer = customer name who sent the new issue email to our support team
2) Customer Contact = the main customer contact, currently populated by the custom list

I created these two custom fields because we have external customers who call or email issues they have using our hosted software.  Currently our system creates a simple new issue when a customer sends an email to our support email account.  Our support team then goes in and cleans up the data and makes sure that all the required Jira fields have data, the comments are good, reproducible steps, etc.  (Currently we do not strip out the customer domain name to auto-populate the Customer custom field, but I might try doing that soon.)

Our support team is asking that I add the following two new customer fields:

3) Customer phone number
4) Customer connection / login info

What I would like to implement is a system that goes something like this:

- Customer name gets inputted (either automatically by grabbing domain name of customer email address or manually by our support team) into the Customer custom field. Customer name selected should be "pushed" into the Customer Contact Select List to help sub-select values for that particular customer.
- The Customer Contact Select list should be "smart" or dynamic in that some pre-processing is done where the Customer name is grabbed so that it doesn't show ALL customers contacts for the tech support person to select, it just shows them the customer contacts for the customer that was selected.
- Along with the filtered customer contacts, I would want to only see the Customer phone number for the contact that was populated in the Customer Contact select list.
- And finally I would want to see the Customer connection information for the particular Customer that was selected.I've done this type of smart combo boxes in the past when I created Java / Database applications, so I have a feeling that this is possible in Jira.  I'm just looking for the easiest way to implement this.  It seems like there might be some external plugins that might help do this (ex. the values for the Custom fields are stored in a database table so they can be queried and the proper filtered result sets can be populated into the select lists.), or maybe using post functions (update issue), etc.  But before I spent more effort investigating, I know this sort of thing has to be somewhere common and wanted to ask the Jira admin experts what the best practice would be for this type of functionality in custom fields.  Please share your experience with how to solve this type of scenario.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way that tells how to import multiple options at once. Probably that would help u.

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/92385/importing-project-from-another-jira-instance-how-do-we-mass-import-custom-field-multi-select-options?page=1#92622

**EDIT**
and here is the complete code to update another select list using new select list.

[How to add new values to select list field in jira dynamically or using plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892537/how-to-add-new-values-to-select-list-field-in-jira-dynamically-or-using-plug-in/23198416#23198416)