# How to add new values to select list field in jira dynamically or using plug-in

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

Here is the my use case.
1. I have a "Customer Name" text field and "All Customers" single select list. 
2. When issue is resolved I want to pick value present in "Customer Name" and want to add in "All Customers".

I am able to achieve this If a value to be added is already present in "All Customers". But I want to populate "All Customers" field with new value if it is not present already so that in future it is available for selection.
How to do this? is it possible to do so?

Comment: JIRA doesn't provide a way to update the options in a select list based on the value in an issue. That could be done by creating a new custom field type. Or perhaps by making All Customers a labels field and using JIRA 6.3 (not out yet) to restrict who can edit the labels

Comment: @mdoar fortunately i found way to do this. Just see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

and I found my answer. Here is the complete code. its jira plugin that raises on resolved event and takes value from one custom field and populate another one. Hope that helps other people.

```
package com.spmsoftware.plugin.listeners;

import com.atlassian.event.api.EventListener;
import com.atlassian.event.api.EventPublisher;
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent;
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventType;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.manager.OptionsManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.option.Option;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.option.Options;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.config.FieldConfig;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.config.FieldConfigScheme;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * User: adnan
 * Date: 5/4/14
 * Time: 4:49 PM
 */
public class IssueUpdateListener  implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(IssueUpdateListener.class);

    private final EventPublisher eventPublisher;
   // private final JiraAuthenticationContext authenticationContext;

    public IssueUpdateListener(EventPublisher eventPublisher) {
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
       // this.authenticationContext = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        eventPublisher.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        eventPublisher.unregister(this);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onIssueEvent(IssueEvent issueEvent) {
        Long eventTypeId = issueEvent.getEventTypeId();
        Issue issue = issueEvent.getIssue();
        if (eventTypeId.equals(EventType.ISSUE_RESOLVED_ID)) {
            MutableIssue mutableIssue = getMutableIssue(issue);
            CustomField customerNameCF = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObjectByName("Customer Name");
            CustomField allCustomersCF = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObjectByName("All Customers");
            Object customerNameVal = mutableIssue.getCustomFieldValue(customerNameCF);
            Option newOptions = addOptionToCustomField(allCustomersCF, customerNameVal.toString());
            LOGGER.info("New updated option {}" + newOptions);
        }
    }

    private MutableIssue getMutableIssue(Issue issue) {
        MutableIssue mutableIssue;
        if (issue instanceof MutableIssue)   {
            mutableIssue = (MutableIssue)issue;
        } else {
            mutableIssue = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueObject(issue.getKey());
        }
        return mutableIssue;
    }


    public Option addOptionToCustomField(CustomField customField, String value) {
        Option newOption = null;
        if (customField != null) {
            List<FieldConfigScheme> schemes = customField.getConfigurationSchemes();
            if (schemes != null && !schemes.isEmpty()) {
                FieldConfigScheme sc = schemes.get(0);
                Map configs = sc.getConfigsByConfig();
                if (configs != null && !configs.isEmpty()) {
                    FieldConfig config = (FieldConfig) configs.keySet().iterator().next();
                    OptionsManager optionsManager = ComponentAccessor.getOptionsManager();
                    Options l = optionsManager.getOptions(config);
                    int nextSequence = l.isEmpty() ? 1 : l.getRootOptions().size() + 1;
                    newOption = optionsManager.createOption(config, null, (long) nextSequence, value);
                }
            }
        }

        return newOption;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution @MohdAdnan, we've a similar situtation. But after trying the above code, the listener adds the new value entered in text field to the select list options three times. I've just implemented the same above code. So multilpe duplicates options are added to the Select List field each time a new value is entered.

Comment: @Naren you can check uniqueness and add option only when it is not available.

Comment: I tried checking the uniqueness before adding the new value as an option to the Select List field. Below is the check that I've applied - 'code'if(!options.contains(value)) 
 {
  int nextSequence = options.isEmpty() ? 1 : options.size() + 1;
  newOption = optionsManager.createOption(fieldConfig, null, new Long (nextSequence), value);} 'code'

Comment: use this method rather- pass rootOptions to it along with new value

 private boolean newValueAlreadyPresent(List<Option> rootOptions, String value) {
        for (Option o : rootOptions) {
            if (o.getValue().equals(value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }